# Disable the error of http method server in browser console Angular 8

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, disable

I use Angular 8 and I want disable any errors HTTP in browser console, like this :

*`zone-evergreen.js:2828 POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)`*

In my Error-Interceptor.ts
I use this code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private _tokenService: TokenService,
    private _routesService: RoutesService,
    private _toastService: ToastService
  ) { }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          this._tokenService.logout();
          this._routesService.navigateToRoute("login");
        }
        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        this._toastService.showError(error, '');
        // return throwError(error);
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled errors go to the browser and **cannot** be stopped from showing the error. You may if you want can control the display of errors directly in the browser using one of the many filters.

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Additionally, if you are using Digest Authentication Scheme, the 401 Unauthorized error cannot be bypassed. The first invocation of the protected URL will return 401 Unauthorized error by design. More details [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-6).

Comment: WOW :):) Thanks, but I want to disable this in angular options

Comment: Like I've mentioned in the answer, unhandled errors cannot be stopped from being displayed in the browser. You can however, if you want, disable user generated logs and errors by adding `console.log = function() {}` and `console.error = function() {}` to your main.ts file respectively.

Comment: You could also call [`console.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) anytime to clear the console. But it clears the console only at that instant. It does not clear the errors generated after it is called.